# Position of focus of full width slider header images using CSS

Tags: css, image, slider, position

I want to set the focus of the slider full width header images to the centre. I have tried to use background-position but this doesn't work as I think a different method to background-URL is used.

Please see link below. The image is cropped to fit the height. You can see the image of the hotel room is focused at the top of the image. I want to set the focus on the centre of the image to show the important parts of the image. I know I can optimise image to fit, but I want to keep original height of image for the lightbox.

http://y1y.036.myftpupload.com/hotel/test?check_in=15-05-2020&check_out=22-05-2020&currency=JPY&v=8c1b67db499d

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider providing codes to explain it better

Comment: Sorry I don't have any codes. Does the explanation and link not make sense? The image is cropped to fit the height and I want the image to be focused in the centre instead of from the top.

Answer (score 1):

Try this styling:

```
.outer-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 400px; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.outer-container img {
    flex: none;
}
```